# How to secure a Rest web service with OpenAM as OAuth2 provider

Tags: rest, active-directory, oauth-2.0, openam

I developed a Rest web service with Play! Framework. I aim to secure access to this WS. I'm discovering OAuth2 and it seems to be a good solution in my case. However, instead of using an external OAuth2 provider, I prefer to manage this part myself. So, I installed the last snapshot of OpenAM (12.0.0), which can do this. I have an instance of Active Directory on which the authentication should be based.

I have access to the documentation but I don't know how proceed. I would like to have some tracks.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately.

Comment: Ugg, OpenAM looks great but overly complex for what I need (Cross App account management with OAuth).   But I found this https://github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/oauth2_provider   It looks intresting...

Comment: These projects also look promising : https://github.com/OpenConextApps/apis and http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/
Anyway please share if you find a good alternative to OpenAM or figure out how to get it working as a provider :).   Good Luck!